# Creating black and white copy of an image

Tags: php, images

I want to duplicate a image and convert it to BW with a new name but I get this warning when I try to save it with `imagejpeg()`:

> PHP Warning: 
>   imagejpeg(/srv/www/raquelfriera.test/current/web/app/uploads/2018/02/2018/02/one-year-womens-performance-10-400x266-bw.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

1. I create the image from a custom size `img-400`.
2. Apply filters.
3. String replace to add `-bw` at the end of the file name.
4. save it with imagejpeg( $image, $dest );

All this inside a filter hook `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`. This way I can create the images when upload or `wp media regenerate`.

This is the entire function:

```
function bw_filter($meta) {
  $path = wp_upload_dir();
  /* get dirname of file to get correct date folder */
  $subdir = trailingslashit(dirname($meta['file']));
  /* get basedir on path to get uploads folder */
  $file = trailingslashit($path['basedir']).$subdir.$meta['sizes']['img-400']['file'];
  $str = str_replace(".", "-bw.", $subdir.$meta['sizes']['img-400']['file']);
  $dest = trailingslashit($path['basedir']).$subdir.$str;
  list($orig_w, $orig_h, $orig_type) = @getimagesize($file);


  switch ($orig_type) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
      $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
      imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
      imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -30);
      imagegif( $image, $dest );
    break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
      $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
      imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
      imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -30);
      imagepng( $image, $dest );
    break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
      imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
      imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -30);
      imagejpeg( $image, $dest );
    break;
  }
  return $meta;
}
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\bw_filter',10,2);
```

How can I save the image to upload dir in a new file?

Comment: maybe this errors come because the directory doesn't exist. try this before to create the file `if (!is_dir($dir)) {mkdir($dir);}`

Comment: Looks like you're adding year and month twice for some reason.  Is there  a purpose to that?

Comment: Just throwing it out there, but the answers to this question may be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css

Comment: Is there a reason you actually need to duplicate and save the black and white image? If it's just for use on your site then applying the following css to the original will have the same effect `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);`

Comment: Actually IE doesn't support it: https://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a repeating year and month in the folder path on that error you are showing.

> /2018/02/2018/02/

Could that be it?